# Como criar um ListView customizado dentro de um Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

Boa Noite

Pesquisei bastante a respeito, porém não consegui entender direito o conceito.

Tenho uma aplicação Android que utiliza Fragments. Preciso inserir um ListView customizado com uma imagem e diversos textos, porém não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Em uma Activity normal, bastaria criar um Adapter personalizado, porém em um Fragment não estou conseguindo o resultado esperado.

Fica a dúvida: como faço para inserir uma ListView customizada dentro de um Fragment?

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada eu lhe aconselharia utilizar o RecyclerView que é muito mais performático e poderoso. Você pode ler mais sobre ele aqui: https://medium.com/android-dev-br/listas-com-recyclerview-d3f41e0d653c. Mas como em sua pergunta você especifica o ListView e eu não quero fugir desse escopo, vamos lá.

Siga esses passos.

1 - Crie o layout da ListView (cars_fragment.xml);

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cars_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2 - Crie agora o layout do item da lista (item_cars_list.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/car_image"
      android:layout_width="48dp"
      android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/car_name"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

3 - Crie um adapter customizado;

```
public class CarsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Car> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Car> cars = null;

    public CarsAdapter(Context context,  List<Car> cars) {
        super(context, 0, cars);
        this.cars = cars;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        Car car = cars.get(position);

        if(view == null)
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cars_list, null);

        ImageView carImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_image);
        carImage.setImageResource(car.getImagem());

        TextView carName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.car_name);
        carName.setText(car.getNome());

        return view;
    }
}
```

- A grande sacada é aqui: na *Activity* você precisaria instanciar sua *view* no `onCreate`. Já em um fragment você infla sua *ListView* no método `onCreateView`.

4 - Inflando a *ListView* no *Fragment*;

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Observe que o primeiro argumento do inflate é o layout com a ListView que criamos no primeiro passo
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cars_fragment, container, false);

        // Aqui você instancia sua ListView
        ListView carsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cars_list);
        List<Car> cars = null; // Obtenha sua lista de objetos aqui

        CarsAdapter carsAdapter = new carsAdapter(getActivity(), cars);
        carsList.setAdapter(carsAdapter);
        return view;
    }
```

Espero que isso possa te ajudar.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado. Graças à sua ajuda consegui fazer o meu código funcionar. Somente um detalhe, na linha em que você executa o código "CarsAdapter carsAdapter = new carsAdapter(this, cars);" eu precisei usar um "this.getActivity()" para que a lista fosse exibida. Agradeço demais pela atenção, abraço!

Comment: Fico muito feliz em ter ajudado você @MatheusSocoloskiVelho! Eu me esqueci que devemos obter a referência da activity e não do fragment. Me desculpe. Vou corrigir na resposta e qualquer coisa estamos aí. Abraço!